# MySQL user privileges for testing Django app

Tags: mysql, django, testing, django-3.0

I am using MySQL with Django. Are my only choices for allowing testing the following? I don't want to `keepdb`.

1. `GRANT ALL ON *.* to '<user>'@'localhost'` so that the user can create test databases, etc.
2. Test on sqlite which is almost the same thing but isn't MySQL and important if I am testing for everything.

Option 1 seems a little unsafe and Option 2 still leaves the door open for untested areas.

Is there another option in terms of the privileges I can grant or ways to think about it?

What is the Django/python recommended way to do it? Option 1 is what my search has yielded so far.

Comment: What about docker/docker-compose ?

Comment: I don't know anything about it; is there a primer/guide/documentation specifically addressing this that you can point me to? Thank you.

Comment: [docker](https://www.docker.com/) is a very vast topic. BTW, I have been using [docker-compose.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) for running the test in Gitlb Runner and it seems fine (~3 years)